# Get route parameters of child route

Tags: angular

**EDIT : Actually, if I do this in the child `DancersAddComponent` the query will work, but if I do in the parent route `DancersComponent` it wont**

Using angular 9 I have a main module routing that will return the correct module to load depending on the app state =>

```
const splitter = () =>
  import('@app/app-routing-handler.module').then((module) => module.AppRoutingHandlerModule)

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: splitter,
  },
]
```

Then in My app have have many module that each lazyload a module with his own routes.

Everything works fine when I input the different urls, the correct components are displayed.

In one of my sub routing module I have the following routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DancersComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dancers/:id/add,
        component: DancersAddComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

I tried to get the route param `id` in my DancersComponent using the following

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
      console.log(params)
    })
  }
```

but those parameters are always empty.

I believe it's because it s a route nested in another module, that is also nested in another route.

Is there a way to get the parameters of those sub routing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out, use

```
this.route.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
  console.log(params)
})
```